# How springboot and maven maintain the dependency version?

Tags: spring-boot, maven

For example, I want to upgrade the jackson-databind version. With below pom.xml, the version upgrade to 2.15.2, however I do not define the version of jackson-databind. Only define the jackson-bom.version. How springboot maintain it? Even related jackson version of spring upgrade to 2.15.2.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <jackson-bom.version>2.15.2</jackson-bom.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5iMc.png)

Want to know the principle

Comment: Spring Boot uses parent pom and bill of material to manage its dependencies: https://reflectoring.io/maven-bom/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BOM is a special POM file that groups dependency versions that are known to be valid and tested to work together - [BOM in maven](https://dzone.com/articles/the-bill-of-materials-in-maven). Jackson BOM contains a complete set of consistent versions of jackson dependencies - [Jackson BOM](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-bom)